# Fastest way to factor powers of two?

Tags: java, math, bit-manipulation

I'm writing some code where I'd like to be able to factorise out powers of two quickly.

I've noticed something handy about numbers with powers of two in them when represented in binary:

```
27959296 = 0b1101010101010000000000000 = 110101010101 * 10000000000000 = 3413 * 2^13
```

If I could bitshift those zeros out I'd be left with the other factors. After looking over google, SO and a few other places, and playing with Wolfram|alpha I can't see a good way of doing this without iterating over and dividing by two/bit shifting on each operation. If I convert it into a string I might be able to use string manipulation to split those zeros off.

I've tried using the rule of logs to say that:

```
log base 2(27959296) = log(3413 * 2^13)/log(2) = 13+ log(3413)/log(2)
```

But I'm missing the logic that differentiates between the 13 and the `log(3413)/log(2)` from 24.73.... that would give an 'easy' answer.

Finally there is a method `numberOfTrailingZeros` that gives me a good answer, but I don't know how it woorks under the hood, nor how fast it is.

Here is a SSCCE for that method (scavanged from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/integer_numberoftrailingzeros.htm)):

```
import java.lang.*;

public class IntegerDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     int i = 27959296;
     System.out.println("Number = " + i);

     /* returns the string representation of the unsigned integer value 
     represented by the argument in binary (base 2) */
     System.out.println("Binary = " + Integer.toBinaryString(i));

     /* returns the number of zero bits following the lowest-order 
     ("rightmost") one-bit */
     System.out.print("Number of trailing zeros = ");
     System.out.println(Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(i));  
   }
}
```

What is the fastest method? Am I going the wrong way with bit shifting?

Comment: The computer already stores the number in binary, and can easily shift away the zeros.  I wouldn't look to try anything other than bitshifting and `numberOfTrailingZeros`.  But is there a reason to think this is a bottleneck in your program in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros` is blazing fast, and `i >> Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(i)` is likely to be the fastest alternative possible.

Comment: How do you know it's blazingly fast?

Comment: It would surely beat converting it to a `String` to count the trailing zeros.

Comment: Because I've done a ton of high-performance math utility optimization, and a lot of benchmarking?  IIRC, `Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros` may actually have an intrinsic implementation; I think I once tried to copy/paste its implementation and got a slower result.

Comment: A quick Caliper benchmark yields the following results:  https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/293b36d3-d010-47c6-90a8-9aa056a2267a#r:scenario.benchmarkSpec.methodName

Comment: Shifting a number is faster than doing any String conversion/other calculation because only one assembly command is involved in shifting, and all CPUs, no matter how primitive support shifting a register (meaning multiplying if you shift left, or dividing if you shift right) without using its ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit) to do any calculation.

Comment: On modern cpus, there is a primitive instruction for doing this. Without that, there is still a faster way -- by adopting the De Bruijn method of finding integer log_2 -- than the solution listed in the Integer class.

Comment: I believe current JVMs actually intrinsify `numberOfTrailingZeros` to the CPU instruction, rather than using the implementation actually written in the class...